# unsupported operand type(s) for +: 'ManagedProperties' and 'float' python 3

Tags: python, typeerror, sympy

```
import numpy as np
import sympy
import math as m
a = 646/100
b = 81/100
c = 484/100
d = 161/100
L = 1614/100 
w = 4
angle = m.atan(d/a)
W_tot = w*L/2
x_tot = L/3
Rax,Ray,Re = sympy.S('Rax,Ray,Re')
eq1 = sympy.Eq(-Rax+Re*m.cos(angle),0)
eq2 = sympy.Eq(Ray+Re*m.sin(angle)-W_tot,0)
eq3 = sympy.Eq(Re*m.cos(angle)*(c+d)- W_tot*x_tot,0)
sympy.solve([eq1,eq2,eq3],[Rax,Ray,Re])
```

The code returns `[]`. The answer seems weird, so I tried each equation one by one and put in the numbers directly. However, in eq2, the error happens.

```
eq2 = sympy.Eq(Ray+ 27.748631684*0.241828717496786 - W_tot,0)
sympy.solve([eq2],[Ray])


---------------------------------------------------------------------------
TypeError                                 Traceback (most recent call last)
<ipython-input-13-a25a64f8c655> in <module>
      1 a = m.sin(angle)
      2 print(a)
----> 3 eq2 = sympy.Eq(Ray+ 27.748631684*0.241828717496786 - W_tot,0)
      4 sympy.solve([eq2],[Ray])

TypeError: unsupported operand type(s) for +: 'ManagedProperties' and 'float'
```

Any tips on solving this problem? Python seem to consider Ray as 'ManagedProperties' type

Comment: Ray seems to be keyword in sympy, when i tried with a diffrent variable name it works

Comment: https://docs.sympy.org/latest/modules/geometry/lines.html#sympy.geometry.line.Ray

Answer (score 0):

Use `symbols` to create symbols:

```
Rax, Ray, Re = sympy.symbols('Rax, Ray, Re')
```

Otherwise sympifying `Ray` gives the `Ray` class which is not what you want (this will happen with any name that is already defined in sympy).